# How to texture mesh? Shader vs. generated texture

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh

I managed to create a map divided in chunks. Each one holding a mesh generated by using perlin noise and so on. The basic procedural map method, shown in multiple tutorials.

At this point i took a look at surface shader and managed to write one which fades multiple textures depending on the vertex heights.
This gives me a map which is colored smoothly.

[image: mesh]

In tutorials i watched they seem to use different methods to texture a mesh. So in [this one](https://youtu.be/RDQK1_SWFuc?list=PLFt_AvWsXl0eBW2EiBtl_sxmDtSgZBxB3&t=516) for example a texture is generated for each mesh. This texture will hold a different color depending on the noise value.This texture is applied to the mesh and after that the mesh vertices are displaced depending on the z-value.

This results in a map with sharper borders between the colors giving the whole thing a different look. I believe there is a way to create smoother transitions between the tile-colors by fading them like i do in my shader.

My question is simply what are the pro and cons of those methods. Let's call them "shader" and "texture map". I am lost right now, not knowing in which direction to go.

Comment: FWIW, a shader is "how does light affect this object" whereas a texture is simply "what value goes here." Where `value` can mean a lot of things, depending on how the shader interprets the texture (bump map, specular map, diffuse color, specular color, noise map...).

Comment: So it's better (meaning more flexible) to first apply a texture which than is modified by a shader?

Comment: I mean, the two systems are not comparable, they do different things. Can you do color without a texture? Yes. Can you do color without a shader? No (all materials require a shader, not all shaders require a texture). *How* you want to get the effect you want is largely opinion based.

Comment: Ok got it - so my question is kind of pointless respectively heading nowhere. Let's asume i modify my current setup to get the tile-texture from a texture-atlas/sprite-sheet, what is the proper way to "fade" the textures at the tile-borders? To just calculate an proportion of both (next/last & current-height-color) and use that color?

Comment: That gets opinion based fast. There is no "proper" way. There's really only "ways that work." Some might be more efficient than others, but "best" is not something we can quantify on SO.

Comment: OK thank your for your answers - i guess i got to learn and try out a lot more of the concepts to come up with specific questions.